# use url for generated pages, no query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I want to generate pages with asp.net. I have one page with the content I will show. I know that you can use a query string like this:

```
www.mysite.com/users.aspx?name=pol
```

*With the code for read and place a query string, I have no problems and works very good.*

But for the users it's more friendly to use this:

```
www.mysite.com/users/pol
```

How can you do this? I use ASP.NET, the background language is C#.

Comment: The users couldn't care less what your URL looks like, see Facebook. Anyway what you're looking for is URL routing, try to search: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using URL Routing.

ASP.Net web forms applications doesn't support URL routing by default, but you can easily implement it by registering routes at the start of your application (in Global.asax file) as shown here -

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Comment: Can you add the most important code to your question? If the link goes offline...